# MS Access table linking to another table - How?

Tags: ms-access

I have a client database that I'm working on, which was not written by me. The original programmer seems to have linked two tables together (see screen grab). The linking is wrong and needs changing, but I can't find where the settings are to change it. When I look at the table in "Design View" I get no clues there. Does anyone know how I can get to see the settings of what is going on? Many thanks in advance.[image]

UPDATE: The major issue us that I cannot seem to import this table into SQL:

[image]

UPDATE2: Seems to be to do with the field "Accounting Periods". The post-process report says it has written 14 rows. I thought at first that it might not like the empty values in that field, but the blanks do not start until row 16 (see below). Most confusing....

[image]

Comment: The error message tells another story - nothing about a link error. So?

Comment: Agreed. I have updated the description with new findings. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like an error caused by an enforced relationship or violated database constraint.

If you're looking for relationships, you can find those by going to *Relationships*. It's possible you see the relationship directly, but if you don't, press *Clear Layout*, and then press *All Relationships*. If the relationship has a 1-1 or 1-many indicator, it's enforced. If it doesn't have any indicators, it's not enforced.

Constraints that are not caused by relationships can be difficult. Usually, these are visible in design view by looking at the field's *Validation rule* property, but I haven't found an easy way to view `CHECK` constraints yet.

Subdatasheets are defined either by an enforced one-to-many relationship, if the table has the *Subdatasheet Name* property set to *[Auto]*, or by manually setting the subdatasheet by opening the table in Design View, opening the property pane, and filling in the subdatasheet name, link child fields and link master fields properties.

Comment: When I went into "Design View" of the table, right-clicked on the "Primary Key" field > Properties > and set "sub-datasheet" to "none". It fixed the problem and the SQL import error went away. The SQL message seemed to be a red herring about there being an issue with the "Accounting Periods" table. Many thanks for your help.